# jQuery mobileTaphold event doesn't works on emulator?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created an app in which, when a long press on a button occurs, it will show a confirm box with a message in it. If the user selects ok, it will perform the task; else it will do nothing.

So I have written the code but when i run it on my emulator it does nothing. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tapholder").bind("tapholder",function(){
        var hi=confirm("Do you really want to delete data");
        if(hi==true) {
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql(deleterecord,[id]);
                alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
                parent.location='file:///android_asset/www/index.html';
            });
        }else{
            alert("Data not deleted");
        }
    });
});

<td id="Cancel"><button id="tapholder">DeleteRecord</button></td>
```

Comment: You could try to accept some of your previous answers, your acceptance ration is 0.

Comment: i'm new to this site can you me how to accept answers

Answer (score 1):

Tapholder event dont exist, it should be **[taphold](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/)** and you should also bind it a little bit different, in stead of bind you should use function **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

```
$(document).on("taphold","#tapholder",function(){
    var hi=confirm("Do you really want to delete data");
    if(hi==true){
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql(deleterecord,[id]);
            alert("Record Deleted Successfully");
            parent.location='file:///android_asset/www/index.html';
        });
    }else{
        alert("Data not deleted");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting error 06-07 13:19:20.312: D/CordovaLog(979): TypeError: Result of expression '$(document).on' [undefined] is not a function.
06-07 13:19:20.312: E/Web Console(979): TypeError: Result of expression '$(document).on' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/editpage.html:222

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.Orc2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.Orc2.min.js"></script>

Comment: know i am getting this error 06-07 14:31:26.631: D/CordovaLog(1337): TypeError: Result of expression 'this.call' [undefined] is not a function.
06-07 14:31:26.631: E/Web Console(1337): TypeError: Result of expression 'this.call' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.3.2.js:3032
06-07 14:31:26.671: D/Cordova(1337): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/editpage.html)

Comment: Gajotres it not working its showing that $(document).on is not a function

Comment: Oh your jQuery version is tooo low, you should switch to at least jQuery 1.7 +. Your current version 1.3.2 don't have function on. In case you cant use newer version then stick with bind but I don't think this will work. jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 will not work correctly with any jQuery version lower then 1.7. So if possible use any jQuery version larger then 1.7

Comment: Not to mention speed boost between jQuery version 1.3.2 and 1.7 is HUGE.

Comment: its still not can anyone provide me a link or example for this long press event in phonegap android plzzz